# How to check for the presence of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the `.length` method in a conditional statement that polls the page for the presence of an externally-loaded object (I can't style it with jQuery until it exists):

> ```
> function hackyFunction() {
>   if($('#someObject').length<1)
>   { setTimeout(hackyFunction,50) }
>   else
>   { $('#someObject').someMethod() }}
> ```

Is `length` the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you should use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/). You cannot use `if ($('#someObject')) ...` because the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) return a jQuery object, and any object is truthy in JavaScript.

Answer (score 12):

If you are simply looking for a specific element you can just use `document.getElementById`

```
function hackyFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("someObject")) {
         // Exist
    } else {
         // Doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't agree. If you have multiple checks for an element, the script will be filled with gEBI functions, which is useless if you're *already* including the **entire** jQuery library. Not to mention, in that specific snippet you'd have to invoke it *twice* unless you're not caching it before the `if..else`. And if you use gEBI all over the place you have to remember to wrap jQuery around it or unless you invoke prototypal methods, they will not be defined.

Comment: You're absolutly right, but...^^ In the code snippet from the TO are two jquery-objects invoked for the same element. Also the TO has had selected the 'javascript'-tag only. For this, the vanilla-js solution is absolutely appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `.length` is acceptable and is usually what I use.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an ID there should only ever be one of those, so you could also write:

```
if($('#someObject')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, checking length works fine.

```
if (!$('#someObject').length) {
    console.log('someObject not present');
}
```

Of course with vanilla JavaScript, you can just check with `document.getElementById` (if getting elements by id)

```
if (document.getElementById('someObject')) {
    console.log('someObject exists');
}
```